# How to select other columns of a table when grouping?

Tags: mysql, sql

Please assume this table:

```
// mytable
+--------+-------------+---------+
|  num   | business_id | user_id |
+--------+-------------+---------+
| 3      | 503         | 12      |
| 7      | 33          | 12      |
| 1      | 771         | 13      |
| 2      | 86          | 13      |
| 1      | 772         | 13      |
| 4      | 652         | 14      |
| 4      | 567         | 14      |
+--------+-------------+---------+
```

I need to group it based on `user_id`, So, here is my query:

```
select max(num), user_id from mytable
group by user_id
```

Here is the result:

```
// res
+--------+---------+
|  num   | user_id |
+--------+---------+
| 7      | 12      |
| 2      | 13      |
| 4      | 14      |
+--------+---------+
```

---

Now I need to also get the `business_id` of those rows. Here is the expected result:

```
// mytable
+--------+-------------+---------+
|  num   | business_id | user_id |
+--------+-------------+---------+
| 7      | 33          | 12      |
| 2      | 86          | 13      |
| 4      | 567         | 14      |  -- This is selected randomly, because of the equality of values
+--------+-------------+---------+
```

Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't group.  You filter.  One method uses window functions such as `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id order by num desc) as seqnum
      from mytable t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Another method which can have slightly better performance with an index on `(user_id, num)` is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.num = (select max(t2.num)
               from mytable t2
               where t2.user_id = t.user_id
              );
```

You should think "group by" when you want to summarize rows.  You should think "where" when you want to choose rows with particular characteristics.

Comment: Great .. thanks buddy

Comment: I've tested your query .. it doesn't handle duplicates .. https://i.stack.imgur.com/OApuW.png

Comment: @stack . . . What do you want when there are duplicates?  Your question doesn't specify.  The use of `group by`, in fact, implies that you want just one row per `user_id`, which is what the first query does.